# Pandas: Assign values of column up to a limit set by dictionary values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I remove the `iterrows()`? Can this be done faster with numpy or pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
                   'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
                   'C': np.arange(8)*0  })
print(df)
#      A      B  C
# 0  foo    one  0
# 1  bar    one  0
# 2  foo    two  0
# 3  bar  three  0
# 4  foo    two  0
# 5  bar    two  0
# 6  foo    one  0
# 7  foo  three  0

selDict = {"foo":2, "bar":3}
```

This works:

```
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    if selDict[r["A"]] > 0:
        selDict[r["A"]] -=1         
        df.set_value(i, 'C', 1)

   print df
#      A      B  C
# 0  foo    one  1
# 1  bar    one  1
# 2  foo    two  1
# 3  bar  three  1
# 4  foo    two  0
# 5  bar    two  1
# 6  foo    one  0
# 7  foo  three  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach -

1) Helper functions :

```
def argsort_unique(idx):
    # Original idea : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41242285/3293881 by @Andras
    n = idx.size
    sidx = np.empty(n,dtype=int)
    sidx[idx] = np.arange(n)
    return sidx

def get_bin_arr(grplens, stop1_idx):
    count_stops_corr = np.minimum(stop1_idx, grplens)

    limsc = np.maximum(grplens, count_stops_corr)
    L = limsc.sum()

    starts = np.r_[0,limsc[:-1].cumsum()]

    shift_arr = np.zeros(L,dtype=int)
    stops = starts + count_stops_corr
    stops = stops[stops<L]

    shift_arr[starts] += 1
    shift_arr[stops] -= 1
    bin_arr = shift_arr.cumsum()
    return bin_arr
```

Possibly faster alternative with a loopy slicing based helper function :

```
def get_bin_arr(grplens, stop1_idx):
    stop1_idx_corr = np.minimum(stop1_idx, grplens)    
    clens = grplens.cumsum()
    out = np.zeros(clens[-1],dtype=int)    
    out[:stop1_idx_corr[0]] = 1
    for i,j in zip(clens[:-1], clens[:-1] + stop1_idx_corr[1:]):
        out[i:j] = 1
    return out
```

2) Main function :

```
def out_C(A, selDict):
    k = np.array(selDict.keys())
    v = np.array(selDict.values())
    unq, C  = np.unique(A, return_counts=1)
    sidx3 = np.searchsorted(unq, k)
    lims = np.zeros(len(unq),dtype=int)
    lims[sidx3] = v
    bin_arr = get_bin_arr(C, lims)
    sidx2 = A.argsort()
    out = bin_arr[argsort_unique(sidx2)]    
    return out
```

Sample runs -

Original approach :

```
def org_app(df, selDict):
    df['C'] = 0
    d = selDict.copy()    
    for i, r in df.iterrows():
        if d[r["A"]] > 0:
            d[r["A"]] -=1         
            df.set_value(i, 'C', 1)
    return df
```

Case #1 :

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar res foo bar res foo foo res'.split()})
>>> selDict = {"foo":2, "bar":3, "res":1}
>>> org_app(df, selDict)
      A  C
0   foo  1
1   bar  1
2   foo  1
3   bar  1
4   res  1
5   foo  0
6   bar  1
7   res  0
8   foo  0
9   foo  0
10  res  0
>>> out_C(df.A.values, selDict)
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Case #2 :

```
>>> selDict = {"foo":20, "bar":30, "res":10}
>>> org_app(df, selDict)
      A  C
0   foo  1
1   bar  1
2   foo  1
3   bar  1
4   res  1
5   foo  1
6   bar  1
7   res  1
8   foo  1
9   foo  1
10  res  1
>>> out_C(df.A.values, selDict)
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: Can this help?  My thought were to use dups and limit.. This uses rank. pseudo code. apply "1", return "0" above rank.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671013/ranking-of-numpy-array-with-possible-duplicates

Comment: @Merlin Hmm, don't think `rankdata` can help you here. Also, any such apply method would be essentially looping. If you are dealing with a small number of `keys`, a loopy method/apply could be a better choice. I was assuming large data and decent no. of keys.

Comment: @Merlin Good catch! Edited.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood correctly, you can use cumcount:

```
df['C'] = (df.groupby('A').cumcount() < df['A'].map(selDict)).astype('int')

df
Out: 
     A      B  C
0  foo    one  1
1  bar    one  1
2  foo    two  1
3  bar  three  1
4  foo    two  0
5  bar    two  1
6  foo    one  0
7  foo  three  0
```

Comment: @Merlin well it is vectorized so it is faster than iterrows but pandas handles a lot of different things like NaNs and dtypes so it cannot be as fast as numpy. Not sure how though. Let's wait for Divakar. :)

Comment: Nice trickery on conjuring me up! ;) Well was a lot more effort than I though it would be.

Comment: @Divakar Yeah I wasn't also expecting it to be complicated. It's better though  - more for me to learn. :)

Answer (score 1):

[`scipy.stats.rankdata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html) can help here. In order to derive the rank of each element within its bucket, we take the difference between the "min" and "ordinal" methods:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import rankdata as rd
>>> rd(df.A, 'ordinal') - rd(df.A, 'min')
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4])
```

Then we just compare to `df.A.map(selDict)`:

```
df.C = (rd(df.A, 'ordinal') - rd(df.A, 'min') < df.A.map(selDict)).astype(int)
```

This may be a little inefficient (calling rankdata twice), but using the optimized routines in scipy should make up for that.

If you can't use scipy you can use repeated `argsort()` for the "ordinal" method and my solution using `unique` and `bincount` for the "min" method:

```
>>> _, v = np.unique(df.A, return_inverse=True)
>>> df.A.argsort().argsort() - (np.cumsum(np.concatenate(([0], np.bincount(v)))))[v]
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2
6    3
7    4
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Then compare to `df.A.map(selDict)` as above.