# How to efficiently get all the valid re-ranked permutations from a list when it has duplicate ranks inside it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, permutation, ranking

Let's suppose two people got the similar marks or scores. Theoretically you can assign them the same rank but what if there is a constraint that there can't be duplicate ranks.

Examples:

- Input: [1,1,2] can be written as Output: [1,2,3], [2,1,3]
- Input: [1,1,1] and can be written as ANY permutation because any of the position can have any rank possible Output: [1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2,2,3].... [3,2,1]
- Input: [2,1,2] can be written as Output: [2,1,3], [3,1,2]
- Input: [1,2,3]  has no other permutations so Output = None
- Input: [1,2,2] can be Output: [1,2,3], [1,3,2]

There is [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671013/ranking-of-numpy-array-with-possible-duplicates) but it gives repeated ranks which I can't

I have come up with this code so far which generated the sampling pool from the existing list

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import permutations
import random 


ranks = [1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,4,2]
counter = Counter(ranks)
sorted_counter = dict(sorted(counter.items(), key = lambda x: x[0]))
print(sorted_counter)


range_to_from = {1:(1,counter[1])}
sample_from = {}# wherever you find any rank "i", you can replace it with any number from the range

for key,val in sorted_counter.items():
    if key == 1:
        sample_from[1] = list(range(val+1))
        continue
    else:
        start, end = (range_to_from[key-1][-1]+1, range_to_from[key-1][-1]+val)
        range_to_from[key] = (start,end)
        sample_from[key] = list(range(start,end+1))
```

If you do the below in a `while i != all_possible_perms`, you'll get all possible values but it';; be too costly comparing each and every generated list already:

```
# Get single permutation from the list
new_ranks = []
for item in ranks:
    sub = random.choice(sample_from[item])
    sample_from[item].remove(sub)
    new_ranks.append(sub)

new_ranks
```

Comment: What is the question precisely? What's an example input/output?

Comment: @DjaouadNM I had already put the sample input and outputs in the list manner with logic but again, I have named them again for your ease. Thank you for reminding me the guidelines of the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For input `[1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,4,2]`, I first find the groups of equal-value indices: `[0, 5, 6]`, `[1, 2, 7, 9]`, `[3, 4]` and `[8]`. I get the permutations for each and build the product, so for example I have `x = ((6,0,5), (2,9,7,1), (3,4), (8,))`. Then I chain those and assign ranks from left to right.

```py
from itertools import chain, count, groupby, permutations, product

ranks = [1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,4,2]

key = ranks.__getitem__
groups = (g for k, g in groupby(sorted(range(len(ranks)), key=key), key))
for x in product(*map(permutations, groups)):
    for i, ranks[i] in zip(chain(*x), count(1)):
        pass
    print(ranks)
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVDNasMwDGZXP4WOdvEG6XYYgx72HKUEL3VSk9oy_oFmr7JLL9tD7Wkm28lhEgYJ-fuRvn78ki7o7vfvnMbH19-H9zGgBZN0SIjXCMZ6DAmGizJOwoDZJQlTwOw_FgleB5uTSgZdpC7gOQ-JsaDcHOEAx07uKZ8pO1nqF7k_MTbrhYb101PfTzqRnO17VmkLjk8wYoCZlMC4TY5HcqLPnICT5lfteKUQQgIxHui1SghW0LcCXS3xnVWe_3fb1IR4Y0BREEY2U0dzKthP43ndm-9uYt2ddxughFcx1sYHQ7Nmp11yPeh22D8)):

```
[1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 2, 3, 6, 10, 7]
[1, 4, 5, 9, 8, 2, 3, 6, 10, 7]
[1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 2, 3, 7, 10, 6]
[1, 4, 5, 9, 8, 2, 3, 7, 10, 6]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 2, 3, 5, 10, 7]
[1, 4, 6, 9, 8, 2, 3, 5, 10, 7]
[1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3, 5, 10, 6]
[1, 4, 7, 9, 8, 2, 3, 5, 10, 6]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 2, 3, 7, 10, 5]
[1, 4, 6, 9, 8, 2, 3, 7, 10, 5]
[1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3, 6, 10, 5]
[1, 4, 7, 9, 8, 2, 3, 6, 10, 5]
[1, 5, 4, 8, 9, 2, 3, 6, 10, 7]
[1, 5, 4, 9, 8, 2, 3, 6, 10, 7]
[1, 5, 4, 8, 9, 2, 3, 7, 10, 6]
[1, 5, 4, 9, 8, 2, 3, 7, 10, 6]
[1, 6, 4, 8, 9, 2, 3, 5, 10, 7]
[1, 6, 4, 9, 8, 2, 3, 5, 10, 7]
[1, 7, 4, 8, 9, 2, 3, 5, 10, 6]
[1, 7, 4, 9, 8, 2, 3, 5, 10, 6]
[1, 6, 4, 8, 9, 2, 3, 7, 10, 5]
[1, 6, 4, 9, 8, 2, 3, 7, 10, 5]
[1, 7, 4, 8, 9, 2, 3, 6, 10, 5]
[1, 7, 4, 9, 8, 2, 3, 6, 10, 5]
[1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 2, 3, 4, 10, 7]
[1, 5, 6, 9, 8, 2, 3, 4, 10, 7]
[1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3, 4, 10, 6]
[1, 5, 7, 9, 8, 2, 3, 4, 10, 6]
[1, 6, 5, 8, 9, 2, 3, 4, 10, 7]
[1, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 3, 4, 10, 7]
[1, 7, 5, 8, 9, 2, 3, 4, 10, 6]
[1, 7, 5, 9, 8, 2, 3, 4, 10, 6]
[1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3, 4, 10, 5]
[1, 6, 7, 9, 8, 2, 3, 4, 10, 5]
[1, 7, 6, 8, 9, 2, 3, 4, 10, 5]
[1, 7, 6, 9, 8, 2, 3, 4, 10, 5]
[1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 2, 3, 7, 10, 4]
[1, 5, 6, 9, 8, 2, 3, 7, 10, 4]
[1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3, 6, 10, 4]
[1, 5, 7, 9, 8, 2, 3, 6, 10, 4]
[1, 6, 5, 8, 9, 2, 3, 7, 10, 4]
[1, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 3, 7, 10, 4]
[1, 7, 5, 8, 9, 2, 3, 6, 10, 4]
[1, 7, 5, 9, 8, 2, 3, 6, 10, 4]
[1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3, 5, 10, 4]
[1, 6, 7, 9, 8, 2, 3, 5, 10, 4]
[1, 7, 6, 8, 9, 2, 3, 5, 10, 4]
[1, 7, 6, 9, 8, 2, 3, 5, 10, 4]
[1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 3, 2, 6, 10, 7]
[1, 4, 5, 9, 8, 3, 2, 6, 10, 7]
[1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 3, 2, 7, 10, 6]
[1, 4, 5, 9, 8, 3, 2, 7, 10, 6]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 3, 2, 5, 10, 7]
[1, 4, 6, 9, 8, 3, 2, 5, 10, 7]
[1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 3, 2, 5, 10, 6]
[1, 4, 7, 9, 8, 3, 2, 5, 10, 6]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 3, 2, 7, 10, 5]
[1, 4, 6, 9, 8, 3, 2, 7, 10, 5]
[1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 3, 2, 6, 10, 5]
[1, 4, 7, 9, 8, 3, 2, 6, 10, 5]
[1, 5, 4, 8, 9, 3, 2, 6, 10, 7]
[1, 5, 4, 9, 8, 3, 2, 6, 10, 7]
[1, 5, 4, 8, 9, 3, 2, 7, 10, 6]
[1, 5, 4, 9, 8, 3, 2, 7, 10, 6]
[1, 6, 4, 8, 9, 3, 2, 5, 10, 7]
[1, 6, 4, 9, 8, 3, 2, 5, 10, 7]
[1, 7, 4, 8, 9, 3, 2, 5, 10, 6]
[1, 7, 4, 9, 8, 3, 2, 5, 10, 6]
[1, 6, 4, 8, 9, 3, 2, 7, 10, 5]
[1, 6, 4, 9, 8, 3, 2, 7, 10, 5]
[1, 7, 4, 8, 9, 3, 2, 6, 10, 5]
[1, 7, 4, 9, 8, 3, 2, 6, 10, 5]
[1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 3, 2, 4, 10, 7]
[1, 5, 6, 9, 8, 3, 2, 4, 10, 7]
[1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 3, 2, 4, 10, 6]
[1, 5, 7, 9, 8, 3, 2, 4, 10, 6]
[1, 6, 5, 8, 9, 3, 2, 4, 10, 7]
[1, 6, 5, 9, 8, 3, 2, 4, 10, 7]
[1, 7, 5, 8, 9, 3, 2, 4, 10, 6]
[1, 7, 5, 9, 8, 3, 2, 4, 10, 6]
[1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 2, 4, 10, 5]
[1, 6, 7, 9, 8, 3, 2, 4, 10, 5]
[1, 7, 6, 8, 9, 3, 2, 4, 10, 5]
[1, 7, 6, 9, 8, 3, 2, 4, 10, 5]
[1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 3, 2, 7, 10, 4]
[1, 5, 6, 9, 8, 3, 2, 7, 10, 4]
[1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 3, 2, 6, 10, 4]
[1, 5, 7, 9, 8, 3, 2, 6, 10, 4]
[1, 6, 5, 8, 9, 3, 2, 7, 10, 4]
[1, 6, 5, 9, 8, 3, 2, 7, 10, 4]
[1, 7, 5, 8, 9, 3, 2, 6, 10, 4]
[1, 7, 5, 9, 8, 3, 2, 6, 10, 4]
[1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 2, 5, 10, 4]
[1, 6, 7, 9, 8, 3, 2, 5, 10, 4]
[1, 7, 6, 8, 9, 3, 2, 5, 10, 4]
[1, 7, 6, 9, 8, 3, 2, 5, 10, 4]
[2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 1, 3, 6, 10, 7]
[2, 4, 5, 9, 8, 1, 3, 6, 10, 7]
[2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 1, 3, 7, 10, 6]
[2, 4, 5, 9, 8, 1, 3, 7, 10, 6]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 1, 3, 5, 10, 7]
[2, 4, 6, 9, 8, 1, 3, 5, 10, 7]
[2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 5, 10, 6]
[2, 4, 7, 9, 8, 1, 3, 5, 10, 6]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 1, 3, 7, 10, 5]
[2, 4, 6, 9, 8, 1, 3, 7, 10, 5]
[2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 6, 10, 5]
[2, 4, 7, 9, 8, 1, 3, 6, 10, 5]
[2, 5, 4, 8, 9, 1, 3, 6, 10, 7]
[2, 5, 4, 9, 8, 1, 3, 6, 10, 7]
[2, 5, 4, 8, 9, 1, 3, 7, 10, 6]
[2, 5, 4, 9, 8, 1, 3, 7, 10, 6]
[2, 6, 4, 8, 9, 1, 3, 5, 10, 7]
[2, 6, 4, 9, 8, 1, 3, 5, 10, 7]
[2, 7, 4, 8, 9, 1, 3, 5, 10, 6]
[2, 7, 4, 9, 8, 1, 3, 5, 10, 6]
[2, 6, 4, 8, 9, 1, 3, 7, 10, 5]
[2, 6, 4, 9, 8, 1, 3, 7, 10, 5]
[2, 7, 4, 8, 9, 1, 3, 6, 10, 5]
[2, 7, 4, 9, 8, 1, 3, 6, 10, 5]
[2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 1, 3, 4, 10, 7]
[2, 5, 6, 9, 8, 1, 3, 4, 10, 7]
[2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 4, 10, 6]
[2, 5, 7, 9, 8, 1, 3, 4, 10, 6]
[2, 6, 5, 8, 9, 1, 3, 4, 10, 7]
[2, 6, 5, 9, 8, 1, 3, 4, 10, 7]
[2, 7, 5, 8, 9, 1, 3, 4, 10, 6]
[2, 7, 5, 9, 8, 1, 3, 4, 10, 6]
[2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 4, 10, 5]
[2, 6, 7, 9, 8, 1, 3, 4, 10, 5]
[2, 7, 6, 8, 9, 1, 3, 4, 10, 5]
[2, 7, 6, 9, 8, 1, 3, 4, 10, 5]
[2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 1, 3, 7, 10, 4]
[2, 5, 6, 9, 8, 1, 3, 7, 10, 4]
[2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 6, 10, 4]
[2, 5, 7, 9, 8, 1, 3, 6, 10, 4]
[2, 6, 5, 8, 9, 1, 3, 7, 10, 4]
[2, 6, 5, 9, 8, 1, 3, 7, 10, 4]
[2, 7, 5, 8, 9, 1, 3, 6, 10, 4]
[2, 7, 5, 9, 8, 1, 3, 6, 10, 4]
[2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 5, 10, 4]
[2, 6, 7, 9, 8, 1, 3, 5, 10, 4]
[2, 7, 6, 8, 9, 1, 3, 5, 10, 4]
[2, 7, 6, 9, 8, 1, 3, 5, 10, 4]
[3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 1, 2, 6, 10, 7]
[3, 4, 5, 9, 8, 1, 2, 6, 10, 7]
[3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 1, 2, 7, 10, 6]
[3, 4, 5, 9, 8, 1, 2, 7, 10, 6]
[3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 1, 2, 5, 10, 7]
[3, 4, 6, 9, 8, 1, 2, 5, 10, 7]
[3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 5, 10, 6]
[3, 4, 7, 9, 8, 1, 2, 5, 10, 6]
[3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 1, 2, 7, 10, 5]
[3, 4, 6, 9, 8, 1, 2, 7, 10, 5]
[3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 6, 10, 5]
[3, 4, 7, 9, 8, 1, 2, 6, 10, 5]
[3, 5, 4, 8, 9, 1, 2, 6, 10, 7]
[3, 5, 4, 9, 8, 1, 2, 6, 10, 7]
[3, 5, 4, 8, 9, 1, 2, 7, 10, 6]
[3, 5, 4, 9, 8, 1, 2, 7, 10, 6]
[3, 6, 4, 8, 9, 1, 2, 5, 10, 7]
[3, 6, 4, 9, 8, 1, 2, 5, 10, 7]
[3, 7, 4, 8, 9, 1, 2, 5, 10, 6]
[3, 7, 4, 9, 8, 1, 2, 5, 10, 6]
[3, 6, 4, 8, 9, 1, 2, 7, 10, 5]
[3, 6, 4, 9, 8, 1, 2, 7, 10, 5]
[3, 7, 4, 8, 9, 1, 2, 6, 10, 5]
[3, 7, 4, 9, 8, 1, 2, 6, 10, 5]
[3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 1, 2, 4, 10, 7]
[3, 5, 6, 9, 8, 1, 2, 4, 10, 7]
[3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 4, 10, 6]
[3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 1, 2, 4, 10, 6]
[3, 6, 5, 8, 9, 1, 2, 4, 10, 7]
[3, 6, 5, 9, 8, 1, 2, 4, 10, 7]
[3, 7, 5, 8, 9, 1, 2, 4, 10, 6]
[3, 7, 5, 9, 8, 1, 2, 4, 10, 6]
[3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 4, 10, 5]
[3, 6, 7, 9, 8, 1, 2, 4, 10, 5]
[3, 7, 6, 8, 9, 1, 2, 4, 10, 5]
[3, 7, 6, 9, 8, 1, 2, 4, 10, 5]
[3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 1, 2, 7, 10, 4]
[3, 5, 6, 9, 8, 1, 2, 7, 10, 4]
[3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 6, 10, 4]
[3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 1, 2, 6, 10, 4]
[3, 6, 5, 8, 9, 1, 2, 7, 10, 4]
[3, 6, 5, 9, 8, 1, 2, 7, 10, 4]
[3, 7, 5, 8, 9, 1, 2, 6, 10, 4]
[3, 7, 5, 9, 8, 1, 2, 6, 10, 4]
[3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 5, 10, 4]
[3, 6, 7, 9, 8, 1, 2, 5, 10, 4]
[3, 7, 6, 8, 9, 1, 2, 5, 10, 4]
[3, 7, 6, 9, 8, 1, 2, 5, 10, 4]
[2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 3, 1, 6, 10, 7]
[2, 4, 5, 9, 8, 3, 1, 6, 10, 7]
[2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 3, 1, 7, 10, 6]
[2, 4, 5, 9, 8, 3, 1, 7, 10, 6]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 3, 1, 5, 10, 7]
[2, 4, 6, 9, 8, 3, 1, 5, 10, 7]
[2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 3, 1, 5, 10, 6]
[2, 4, 7, 9, 8, 3, 1, 5, 10, 6]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 3, 1, 7, 10, 5]
[2, 4, 6, 9, 8, 3, 1, 7, 10, 5]
[2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 3, 1, 6, 10, 5]
[2, 4, 7, 9, 8, 3, 1, 6, 10, 5]
[2, 5, 4, 8, 9, 3, 1, 6, 10, 7]
[2, 5, 4, 9, 8, 3, 1, 6, 10, 7]
[2, 5, 4, 8, 9, 3, 1, 7, 10, 6]
[2, 5, 4, 9, 8, 3, 1, 7, 10, 6]
[2, 6, 4, 8, 9, 3, 1, 5, 10, 7]
[2, 6, 4, 9, 8, 3, 1, 5, 10, 7]
[2, 7, 4, 8, 9, 3, 1, 5, 10, 6]
[2, 7, 4, 9, 8, 3, 1, 5, 10, 6]
[2, 6, 4, 8, 9, 3, 1, 7, 10, 5]
[2, 6, 4, 9, 8, 3, 1, 7, 10, 5]
[2, 7, 4, 8, 9, 3, 1, 6, 10, 5]
[2, 7, 4, 9, 8, 3, 1, 6, 10, 5]
[2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 3, 1, 4, 10, 7]
[2, 5, 6, 9, 8, 3, 1, 4, 10, 7]
[2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 3, 1, 4, 10, 6]
[2, 5, 7, 9, 8, 3, 1, 4, 10, 6]
[2, 6, 5, 8, 9, 3, 1, 4, 10, 7]
[2, 6, 5, 9, 8, 3, 1, 4, 10, 7]
[2, 7, 5, 8, 9, 3, 1, 4, 10, 6]
[2, 7, 5, 9, 8, 3, 1, 4, 10, 6]
[2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 1, 4, 10, 5]
[2, 6, 7, 9, 8, 3, 1, 4, 10, 5]
[2, 7, 6, 8, 9, 3, 1, 4, 10, 5]
[2, 7, 6, 9, 8, 3, 1, 4, 10, 5]
[2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 3, 1, 7, 10, 4]
[2, 5, 6, 9, 8, 3, 1, 7, 10, 4]
[2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 3, 1, 6, 10, 4]
[2, 5, 7, 9, 8, 3, 1, 6, 10, 4]
[2, 6, 5, 8, 9, 3, 1, 7, 10, 4]
[2, 6, 5, 9, 8, 3, 1, 7, 10, 4]
[2, 7, 5, 8, 9, 3, 1, 6, 10, 4]
[2, 7, 5, 9, 8, 3, 1, 6, 10, 4]
[2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 1, 5, 10, 4]
[2, 6, 7, 9, 8, 3, 1, 5, 10, 4]
[2, 7, 6, 8, 9, 3, 1, 5, 10, 4]
[2, 7, 6, 9, 8, 3, 1, 5, 10, 4]
[3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 2, 1, 6, 10, 7]
[3, 4, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 6, 10, 7]
[3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 2, 1, 7, 10, 6]
[3, 4, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 7, 10, 6]
[3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 2, 1, 5, 10, 7]
[3, 4, 6, 9, 8, 2, 1, 5, 10, 7]
[3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1, 5, 10, 6]
[3, 4, 7, 9, 8, 2, 1, 5, 10, 6]
[3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 2, 1, 7, 10, 5]
[3, 4, 6, 9, 8, 2, 1, 7, 10, 5]
[3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1, 6, 10, 5]
[3, 4, 7, 9, 8, 2, 1, 6, 10, 5]
[3, 5, 4, 8, 9, 2, 1, 6, 10, 7]
[3, 5, 4, 9, 8, 2, 1, 6, 10, 7]
[3, 5, 4, 8, 9, 2, 1, 7, 10, 6]
[3, 5, 4, 9, 8, 2, 1, 7, 10, 6]
[3, 6, 4, 8, 9, 2, 1, 5, 10, 7]
[3, 6, 4, 9, 8, 2, 1, 5, 10, 7]
[3, 7, 4, 8, 9, 2, 1, 5, 10, 6]
[3, 7, 4, 9, 8, 2, 1, 5, 10, 6]
[3, 6, 4, 8, 9, 2, 1, 7, 10, 5]
[3, 6, 4, 9, 8, 2, 1, 7, 10, 5]
[3, 7, 4, 8, 9, 2, 1, 6, 10, 5]
[3, 7, 4, 9, 8, 2, 1, 6, 10, 5]
[3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 2, 1, 4, 10, 7]
[3, 5, 6, 9, 8, 2, 1, 4, 10, 7]
[3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1, 4, 10, 6]
[3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 2, 1, 4, 10, 6]
[3, 6, 5, 8, 9, 2, 1, 4, 10, 7]
[3, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 4, 10, 7]
[3, 7, 5, 8, 9, 2, 1, 4, 10, 6]
[3, 7, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 4, 10, 6]
[3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1, 4, 10, 5]
[3, 6, 7, 9, 8, 2, 1, 4, 10, 5]
[3, 7, 6, 8, 9, 2, 1, 4, 10, 5]
[3, 7, 6, 9, 8, 2, 1, 4, 10, 5]
[3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 2, 1, 7, 10, 4]
[3, 5, 6, 9, 8, 2, 1, 7, 10, 4]
[3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1, 6, 10, 4]
[3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 2, 1, 6, 10, 4]
[3, 6, 5, 8, 9, 2, 1, 7, 10, 4]
[3, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 7, 10, 4]
[3, 7, 5, 8, 9, 2, 1, 6, 10, 4]
[3, 7, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 6, 10, 4]
[3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1, 5, 10, 4]
[3, 6, 7, 9, 8, 2, 1, 5, 10, 4]
[3, 7, 6, 8, 9, 2, 1, 5, 10, 4]
[3, 7, 6, 9, 8, 2, 1, 5, 10, 4]
```